# UTF8 and Latin Accents string order in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

I have to order a string array alphabetically using a compare function.

It must be case insensitive and accent insensitive.

The best example is :

```
PR is higher than pô
```

**Nice built-in Solution**

*WARNING : you must have intl PHP5 module installed*

```
$collator = new Collator('fr_FR');
$newIsHigher = $collator->compare($new, $base) == 1;
```

Comment: How should you handle non latin chars?, eg Δ δ (greek delta)

Comment: Can't you use sort()?

Comment: Have a look at "urlizer" functions, that could help you to treat accent and case... good example : https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Sluggable/Util/Urlizer.php

Comment: Good question @user574632, this is like a D I guess but I don't really mind these characters, if the fonction handles well latin chars, that would be nice

Comment: thank you @AlterPHP, your solution works but is embedding a lot of code ... Is it the best answer ?

Comment: @Sir_Winn3r, I answered to you lower, sort don't work... dunno why

Comment: @NicolasThery: AlterPHP's solution isn't so much a solution as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to order Unicode strings, you have to perform an operation called [collation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/).

There's a PHP class called [`Collator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php) which does this.

Comment: @Nicolas Thery: you should try this one. I don't know this class but documentation is promiseful !

Comment: This solution is the best one, (I had to make my host install intl extention though) Is there a best practive to use collator in a PHP application ? As a Singleton for example ? At first, I create it locally to use compare function.

Comment: @NicolasThery: I would create it locally.  There are options you can enable/disable/set on the `Collator`, and you wouldn't want to inadvertently cause bugs by polluting global state with those options.

Answer (score -1):

This may be what you need:

```
sort($array, SORT_LOCALE_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```

Comment: this function fails with the following example, I dont know why : 
[SEE THIS SNAPSHOT](http://snag.gy/0JJ2N.jpg).